# DataGridView Cell Validating only when 'Enter' is pressed

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to validate and commit the value entered in the DataGridViewCell **ONLY** when the user presses the 'Enter' key.

If the users presses any other key or mouse button (Arrow keys, Pressing a different cell using the mouse...), I want the behavior to be similar to the 'ESC' key: Move the focus to the new cell and revert the edited cell value to its previous value.

Comment: Why would you give the user such a hard time?  It is completely unguessable, the Enter key has an entirely different use.

Comment: @Passant: The Enter key is a standard confirmation in all of the similar tools I'm working on. Each change in the table will write values to our chip and we want the user to be sure he wants to change the chip values. Another option is putting an apply or check button, but we prefer not to use this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might work.

Handle the CellValidating and cancel any changes unless the last key pressed was enter.

EDIT:

Subclass the DataGridView control with your own class and add the following code to it:

```
  private bool m_lastWasEnter = false;
  public bool LastWasEnter()
  {
     return m_lastWasEnter;
  }
  protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
  {
     m_lastWasEnter = keyData == Keys.Return;
     return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
  }
```

Then you could just add the following to the handler of the CellValidating event:

```
e.Cancel = !instanceOfYourControl.LastWasEnter();
```

This won't give you exactly what you want but should make sure that it'll only stop the editing if the user pressed enter at least and you should be able to modify it to get your exact requirements to be met.

Comment: KeyDown is never called when I'm in edit mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: The KeyPress doesn't capture the 'Enter" key.

Comment: Please see amended answer which will work (this one I had time to test).